# Correct connection to F3 type battery terminals

Tags: batteries, terminal

Looking for deep-cycle lead acid batteries, I come across several models which feature what they call an "F3" type terminal, like this:

[image: F3 battery terminals]

Basically a vertical metal tab with a hole in it. I suppose I could use a faston ring connector, like this:

[image: Faston ring terminal]

And then secure the ring to the metal tab by using the appropriate nut and bolt (in this particular case, M5).
I have a couple of questions regarding it:

1. Are washers needed in this application?
2. Is the material of the bolt important, or regular steel will do the job fine?
3. Is it ok to connect two rings to the same terminal, for the purpose of connecting multiple batteries in series or in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general outline of that ring-terminal-shaped-object is good, but for higher currents and more reliability if there is vibration etc. you might want a brazed or seamless barrel construction, perhaps of copper. You can add shrink tubing to insulate the barrel. It's not a "Faston"(tm) by the way, those are spade terminals.

Image from Grainger.ca

[image]

I would do:
Nut->lockwasher->flat washer (optional)-> Lug -> terminal -> bolt  and torque to recommended for the bolt you are using.

Two or three terminals together are fine.

Material of the bolt is unimportant, just strength,  you can use stainless steel to avoid rust.

Comment: @Russell Teapot: DO NOT put a washer between the wire terminal and battery terminal.

Comment: Yes, terminal (s) and battery are always in direct contact with each other.

Comment: I don't think vibration would be an issue, the idea is to connect the battery to an inverter to power a small (100 W or so) load, so everything will be still. @PeterBennett yes, I already thought about that: it's better to have the wire terminals directly in contact to the battery terminal in order to minimize resistance between them, right?

Comment: @RussellTeapot: Yes - I've heard of battery temrinals melting when someone used a stainless steel washer bedtween the terminals.  Stainless steel hardware is fine to hold the terminals together, but should not be part of the electrical path.